# Eloipool only public Server avaiable

Tags: mining-pools, stratum

Maybe a simple answer

From what I can research so far

Is Eloipool the only public Server avaiable that is not parked or deprecated and that has support for the ASIC chips using stratum  ?

Is there any support for Non Linux based solutions ?

Thanks in Advance

(I can take it Doc give it too me straight) :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloipool & Stratum (Slush) seem to be the only active devs that will support the new ASIC chips and move away from the Getwork method.

Going to port an IronPython Version of Stratum :D

Use this as an educational process & maybe one day get a C# version to support the large body of .NET programmers out there

Thanks to Slush & Luke Jr